# Sending webform submissions to email with csv export of submissions

Tags: webforms, importing-exporting

I need help, because I dont know how to create csv file from submissions and send it as attachment in submission mail.

I have form with some field and after sending webform I need to create custom csv in specific format with values from webform and all this send it like attachment of normal submission mail.

Is there some modul for creating csv from webform, or I need to cook my own custom module to create it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: webform already can create a CSV downloadable file. So it has the code to make the csv output -- you just need to find the right function to call to get the raw output. And then stuff it in an email. You probably need a relatively simple custom module.

Answer (score 1):

As tenken wrote, [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module has a function for that, namely [webform_results_export](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.report.inc/function/webform_results_export/7)

Do you really want a single line of CSV e-mailed when a form is submitted, rather than periodic downloads?  You could modify your e-mail template to print each value, comma, value, but it wouldn't be an attachment.  If you absolutely need an attachment some custom code and/or [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) is the way to go.